# Storyboard segues without stacking?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storyboard

I am developing an app consisting of three screens - a camera capture screen (A), a processing screen (B) and a screen showing the processing result (C).
The app transitions from A to B to C and then back to A again and so on (ie. A->B->C->A->B...) .

If I do this using storyboard segues (A->B, B->C, C->A) the stack of controllers would keep growing.

What would be a good design to solve this?

Comment: No it wont grow...make sure B and C is dealloced while u navigate back to A

Comment: No, if you PUSH from C to A then it will keep getting bigger. You cannot segue backwards. Only forwards. To get from C to A you either need to pop backwards or use an unwind segue.

Comment: `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` should do the trick..

Comment: Unwind segues are your friend here, makes it really easy to achieve what you are after. What version of iOS are you targeting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think everytime you end the flow in viewController C, you must just pop back to view Controller A, to start again any other flow.

Assuming you have a navigation controller, you can do this inside your viewController C, as soon your processing is done:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

In this way, your view controllers B and C will be deallocated everytime you end one flow.